# Oracle - generate records with alphanumeric number and character ascending

Tags: sql, oracle, alphanumeric

I want to have a column which holds customer unique key, consisting of number+character in an ascending order. 
Is it possible to somehow instruct Oracle to generate many records, from 1a to 1z, then 2a to 2z, etc. up until 300000z:

```
CUSTOMER_NUM
------------
10a

10b

10c

.

.

10z

11a

11b

.
```

Best I have reached so far is something like this:

```
select ROUND(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(9,21)), dbms_random.string('l', 1) from dual;
```

Any ideas anyone please? I would like to generate test table with at least 300000 records.

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you want that? A large NUMBER takes no more bytes that what you propose - actually it uses *fewer* bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query should give you desired result.

```
WITH
TABLE1 AS (SELECT LEVEL PART_1   FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 300000),
TABLE2 AS (SELECT CHR(LEVEL+96) AS PART_2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <27)
SELECT PART_1||PART_2 AS KEY_ID FROM TABLE1,TABLE2
```

Comment: This seems very similar to Wernfried Domscheit's answer

Comment: Hell, thanks for the quick and great responds! I think I need to clarify it a bit, I have a column which exists already so I need to populate it with all the above entries. How do I cross it with an INSERT command?

Comment: If you have 300000 rows already in database, you need to update them , if you do not have any rows in the table, then you can use `INSERT INTO YOUR_TABLE SELECT * FROM (above query here)`

Answer (score 0):

You may need something like the following:

```
select alpha || num
from 
(select substr('qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm', level, 1) as alpha from dual connect by level <= 26)
cross join 
(select level as num from dual connect by level <= 2)
order by num, alpha
```

The first query uses a string containing all the characters and splits it into 26 rows containing a single character.

The second query generates a given number of numbers to join with the characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
WITH n AS 
    (SELECT LEVEL AS Num FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL < 10),
c AS 
    (SELECT CHR(LEVEL + 96) AS alpha FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 26)
SELECT num||alpha
FROM n 
    CROSS JOIN c;
```